# How do I restore the ability to do Terminal commands?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I am using Mountain Lion. I added an alias to my ~/.bash_profile file, and now every time I open terminal, it displays the following:

```
Last login: Thu Feb 11 09:50:30 on ttys000
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And then I am not allowed to type anything into terminal. I would like to take the alias out of my ~/.bash_profile file, but don't know how because I can't get to the file through terminal. How can I restore the previous terminal functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just open your text editor of choice and click on File - Open. At the file dialog, hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and type `~/.bash_profile`. Comment out or delete the caustic entry, save your file and re-launch Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Make another admin account on your mac, and use it's terminal to delete or mv your broken .bash_profile file. Or boot in single user mode and do it from there (after mount -uw / of course).

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal preferences, and in the general tab set "shells open with" to `/bin/csh`.  You should now be able to open a new terminal window, `rm ~/.bash_profile`, and switch back to bash.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to your problem.
**The most easy one:**

open any Graphical editor and open your .bash_profile file and delete out your alias or whatever is causing the terminal process to exit.

**Another one solution :**

You can create a new user and login from that user and edit your .bash_profile , (*/user/your_username/.bash_profile*).

Or If you don't want to use any of the graphical methods then try remote login on that system from another system and specify login shell other than bash and edit your .bash_profile(e.g use ssh -t).